# Outlook 2007 - How do I deploy custom toolbar and macro code?

Tags: visual-studio, vba, outlook

Just wondering, do I really have to use Visual Studio to create a simple add-in/toolbar in Outlook 2007? I created a simple toolbar with a button that opens a form. Then I created some macro code in there and run it clicking the button. But now I want to save this thing and deploy it on other computers. How do I do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc563937.aspx) from MSDN Library. Its title is "Deploying a Visual Studio Tools for the Office System 3.0 Solution for the 2007 Microsoft Office System Using Windows Installer (Part 1 of 2)"

Hope this helps

Giovanni

Comment: Really? You have to use Visual Studio? Why does Microsoft do this, have completely different ways of doing these things in the Office suite? This is pretty simple in Word, Excel and even Powerpoint. But Outlook, no you need Visual Studio. Ok, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Well I developed an Outlook plug-in (although it was an Outlook 2003 one) and I remember I used VS and deployed the add-in using a Visual Studio Solution for creating an installer.

Comment: Ok, so was it a lot of hassle to do this? The installer can just be run on the target computer and that's it?

Comment: Once the add-in is finished and working properly, the "Setup" Visual Studio Solution is quite easy to make. The output should be a Setup.exe file and a ProjectName.msi file which will be the ones the users will need to install/uninstall the software. 
On the link I posted, in the "Creating a basic installer" part, you should get all the info you need. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc563937.aspx#VSTO3SolutionPart1_CreatingaBasicInstaller

Good luck with your project

Comment: Btw, I can't really figure out how I actually make the form and the custom toolbar. Any quick pointers?